# Javascript - Array pop polyfill code

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I wanted to write the pop function from scratch what would be the most efficient way? The main issue also is how do I return the originating array without the popped element?

```
Array.prototype.pop = function () {
    var myArray = this;
    var length = myArray.length;
    var element = myArray[length-1];
    myArray = myArray.slice(0,length-1);
    return element;
}

var hello = [1,2,3,4,5];
hello.pop();
5
console.log(hello)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: so you want a polyfill for pop? returning the last element, and changing your array?

Comment: "most efficient way" : see the jsperf answer, the one I put is fastest possible polyfill (still 10x slower :P ). I assume this is just for learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `splice` instead of `slice` - `slice` doesn't modify the original array, whereas `splice` does.

That said, since you're removing the last element, it would be `return myArray.splice(length-1,1);`... which is essentially an alias for `return myArray.pop()` in the first place.

Alternatively, try:

```
var element = myArray[length-1];
myArray.length = length-1;
return element;
```

Comment: The myArray.length = length-1 does not work for empty arrays and throws uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length exceptions, and the splice call in your code needs to access [0] or else it returns a single element or zero element array, instead of the value itself or undefined. :(

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet:

```
Array.prototype.foo = function(){
  return this.splice(this.length-1)[0];
};
```

Returns last element or undefined if zero length and modifies the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh performance... Why do you need that polyfill? Array.prototype.pop is widely supportet!

Anyways I created a little perf test to check that: http://jsperf.com/manual-pop

Comment: I like the jsperf enthusiasm though :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Array.prototype.pop=Array.prototype.pop||function(){
    const len = this.length;
    const itemToBePopped=this[len-1];
    this.splice(len-1,1);
    return itemToBePopped;
}
```